# How can i upgrade magento 2 enterprise version?

Tags: magento2-enterprise

Currently I have used magento 2.1.3 enterprise version. How can i upgrade in latest version ?

Provide some details or hint if anyone have any idea about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the composer.json file, change the version numbers at these places:

```
"type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.3", //change version no. here
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
```

and

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.1.3", //change version no. here
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
```

and then run composer update command.